# Wake-on-Lan causing spurious startup after shutdown (Windows 7 x64)

Tags: windows-7, wake-on-lan

My motherboard (Asus H-87-PRO) has an integrated LAN controller (Realtek 8111G Gigabit). Installed driver from the CD and enabled WoL in BIOS and in OS too, it's working.

The problem is that sometimes when I shut down my computer it shuts down and restarts 3-4 seconds later.

Tried the following workarounds without success:

- Disabled Wake on Lan on pattern match
- Updated with the new LAN driver from Asus's website
- I went to Realtek's website for the newest driver. Updated the NIC driver. The Wake on lan thing seems to be gone, but after an hour Windows somehow can't reach the network. Plug out - plug in, and it works another hour.

Checked `powercfg -LASTWAKE` just after one of these reboots, it showed `Wake History Count - 0` like nothing happened. Checked event logs, nothing there. I have Windows 7 x64 and BIOS up-to-date.

Do You have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Flagged for move to the superuser Q&A forum.

Comment: the weird thing is if I don't install Intel's chipset driver so I use Windows' default chipset driver, works like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

First, update your BIOS to the most current version (if it's not already).  Then enter the bios and find the wake on lan or MagicPacket settings and disable them at the firmware level.  Once you disable it at the firmware level, it's switched off (assuming the board and bios aren't defective).

Edit:  I should note that I found a lot of other users online complaining about the same problem with that motherboard.

Comment: I'd like to use the WoL :)
The problem is the restart effect

Comment: Is there a BIOS update available for the logic board?

Comment: Nope. My BIOS is up-to-date

Comment: In lieu of another answer, you might want to reach out to Asus.  You're not the only person to complain about that problem with that specific mother board.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that too. Thank you anyway :)